# Microsoft Graph Change Notifications using azure functions

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I have a requirement where I have an .exe application which connects to exchange using MS graph API modern authentication with user input tenantId, clientId, and client secret. It pulls meeting rooms available in exchange. I have to stream notifications of any created, updated or deleted meetings from the exchange. I will be giving a UI input field for user to input "notificationURL" and subscribe to it. I am planning to use azure function app to create HTTP trigger as notification URL. Once the notifications start coming will it go in my exe application where I have the java logic or will it be going to the azure function app?

The code I am writing in my java application

```
 GraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider(authProvider).buildClient();

        // Create a new subscription for calendar events with meeting details
        Subscription subscription = new Subscription();
        subscription.resourceUrl = "/me/events";
        subscription.changeType = "created,updated,deleted";
        subscription.notificationUrl = "https://user-input-notification-url";
        subscription.expirationDateTime = OffsetDateTime.now().plusMinutes(15);
        subscription.additionalData.put("@odata.type", "#Microsoft.Graph.ChangeNotificationSubscription");
        subscription.additionalData.put("includeMeetingDetails", true);
        subscription = graphClient.subscriptions().buildRequest().post(subscription);

        // Start listening for notifications
        NotificationHandler notificationHandler = new NotificationHandler();
        CompletableFuture<Void> future = graphClient.subscriptions().byId(subscription.id).buildRequest().getAsync(notificationHandler);

        // Wait for the future to complete (i.e., for the subscription to expire)
        future.get();
    }
```

will this fetch all the calendar events?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample for the Microsoft Graph Change Notifications using azure functions:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sample-azurefunction-csharp/microsoft-graph-sample-azure-function/

Hope this helps.